# About condtions which $f$ and $\phi$ have to satisfy when we apply "indefinite integral by substitution" to $f$.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I am reading "A Course in Analysis vol.2" by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

In this book, the author wrote as follows:

> 1) $f(x)$ is continuous on an interval $I$.
>   2) $\phi(t)$ is continuous and differentiable on an interval $J$, and $\phi(t)$ is continuous on $J$.
>   3) the range of $\phi(t)$ is $I$.
>
> Let $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$.
>   Then, $\frac{d}{dt} F(\phi(t)) = f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t)$.
>   So, $$\int f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt = F(\phi(t)).$$
>   So, $$\int f(x) dx = \int f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt.$$

If I want to get $\int f(x) dx$ and I apply this theorem, I will get $F(\phi(t))$ instead of $F(x)$.

If $\phi$ has the inverse function, then I can get $F(x) = F(\phi(\phi^{-1}(x)))$.

The author didn't assume that $\phi$ has the inverse function.

Why?

Comment: Here $x =\phi (t)$ so $F(\phi (t))$ is same as $F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from condition (1), we have that $x\in I.$ Also, from (3), we have that $\phi(t)\in I.$ Thus, we may compose $f(x)$ with $\phi(t).$ That is, we set $x=\phi(t).$ So getting $F(\phi(t))$ is the same as getting $F(x).$